# Does $e^X=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\text{Id}+\frac{X}{n}\right)^n$ hold for matrices?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let $X$ be a $d \times d$ real matrix, $d>1$. Is it true that
$$
e^X=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\text{Id}+\frac{X}{n}\right)^n\,\,\,?
$$

**Edit:**

It seems that this question is [a duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2498777/104576). To make it more interesting then, I am asking the following:

**Can the density argument via diagonalizable matrices be made rigorous?**

Write $g(X)=e^X, f(X)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\text{Id}+\frac{X}{n}\right)^n
$.

Then $f$ and $g$ agree on diagonalizable matrices (via the classical real-valued case). To deduce they coincide on all matrices, though, requires proving both functions are **continuous**. How do you prove that $f$ is continuous?

(I guess one might try to prove uniform convergence?)

Comment: 1)what is $Id$? 2) can you proceed if $d=1$?

Comment: In a word, _yes_. One promising strategy is that the identity holds for diagonalizable matrices, which are dense, so by continuity it holds everywhere. Another is to consider $\lim(I + tX/n)^{n}$ and show this satisfies the matrix ODE characterizing $\exp$.

Comment: @user619894 It's clear from the context that $\text{Id}$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, what else?

Comment: @jjagmath wanted to make sure.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Why would we even need that? The scalar case proof should just work directly, since powers of $X$ commute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg( I + \frac{A}{n}\bigg)^n = e^A $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1739840/let-a-in-m-n-mathbbr-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-bigg-i-fracan)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/760841/42969

Comment: You only need to consider the case when $X$ is in Jordan normal form. It is obviously true if $X$ is diagonal, so you need to handle the other cases.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. Actually I now found that there is a nice proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2498777/104576. (I tried searching for duplicates before asking but it seems I failed).

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks, that is a nice idea. However, I am not sure how to prove that the relevant functions are continuous. (Please see my edit. Do you have an idea?).

Comment: I haven't carefully written up details, but it looks straightforward to show that for matrices $X$ and $V$, and for real $t$, we have $$(I + \tfrac{1}{n}(X + tV))^n = (I + \tfrac{1}{n}X + \tfrac{t}{n}V)^{n} = (I + \tfrac{1}{n}X)^{n} + (I + \tfrac{1}{n}X)^{n-1}Vt + O(t^2),$$from which we get _differentiability_ of $f$. <> If that works (or suggests another satisfactory approach), please feel free to post!